# Get the second node with same class

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I`m having some trouble parsing some nodes with HtmlAgilityPack.

Here is the problem:

I have many nodes with the class "test", but i want to selct the second one.

If I make something like this:

```
html.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode ("//font[@class='test' and position()=1]")
```

It returns the value that I expected... but if I try to get the second one it returns null... but the question is.. why?

```
html.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode ("//font[@class='test' and position()=2]")
```

This line of code brings me all of them, and i'm really confuse now, because using position()=1 the lib had to return only the first one, right?

```
html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes ("//font[@class='test' and position()=1]")
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: `position()` is the position within the parent element of the `font` element, not the position in the sequence of all font elements of class `text`!

Comment: Thanks Frank! Not confused anymore xD

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct code would be

```
html.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode ("(//font[@class='test'])[2]")
```

The code you used selects the first or second test element within its parent element, not the first or second element in the sequence of all `font` elements of class `test`.

Answer (score 0):

try this but be sure that the index of the nodes starts from [1] and if you overflow that you will have null values returned:

```
string str=htmlSnippet.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='lg:mt-4 px-5 lg:px-0 pb-5 styles_PdpProductContent__sectionBorder__39zAX'])[1]");
```